# Not all code paths return a value.ts(7030) angular

Tags: angular

```
  data:any;
  submit() {
    this.answersValue.forEach((x: { forms: any[]; }) => {
      this.data = {
        pluginconfigform: "pluginconfigform",
        answers: x.forms.map(y => {
          if (y.type != "description") {
            return {
              sectionItemCode: y.code,
              answer: y.answer
            };
          } else {
            delete this.data.answers;
          }
        })
      };
      this.pushData(this.data);
    });
  }
```

**could you let me know how to solve this error? 'Not all code paths return a value.' Thank you.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK8vG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `return y` (or undefined, or anything else conform your other return) after `delete this.data.answers;`. You're using map so you need to return an object that gets mapped back. If you don't want or need to return anything then return undefined so it'll disappear.